# Can't get elements to line up with percentage based values

Tags: css

I need to create a website which will always fill the screen, as a result I'm using percentages.

I'm placing a fixed `header` of `10%` height on top. And a `section` I give a `margin-top` of `10%`. One would presume they would be flush against eachother, but this is not the case. Would anyone want to help?

I have the following HTML:

```
<header></header>
<section></section>
```

with quite a straight forward piece of css:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

header, section {
    width:100%;
}

header {
    height:10%;
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

section {
    background: blue;
    height:90%;
    margin-top:10%;
}
```

You can see this live at http://jsfiddle.net/DanielApt/SeJfu/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probable solution:

Remove `margin` from section. Just write

```
section {
    background: blue;
    height:90%;
    top:10%;
    position:relative;
}
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/SeJfu/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
section {
    background: blue;
    height:90%;
    margin-top:10%;
    position:fixed;
    left: 0;
}
```

Should do the trick (i.e. need it to be fixed positioning and dump the left value)

Answer (score 1):

check if this is what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/Mohinder/nj2UB/

HTML

```
<header></header>
<section></section>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

header, section {
    width:100%;
}

header {
    height:10%;
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

section {
    background: blue;
    height:90%;
   top:10%;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have check it solved your problem.
you remove **"margin"** from section.

**HTML**

```
<header></header>
<section></section>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

header, section {
    width:100%;
}

header {
    height:10%;
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

section {
   background: blue;
    height:90%;
    top:10%;
    position:relative;
}
```